# How to assign backgroundColor to a var in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

seems like a simple question but I don't know JavaScript too well and my search-fu is turning up nothing relevant.

I need to set the backgroundColor property of a textbox to a value set as a String in a var, like so:

```
var pinColor = someFunctionThatReturnsString();
document.getElementById("pin").style.backgroundColor = pinColor;
```

If I put a literal there instead of a var, like '#ffff00', then it works fine.  However a var with the String value '#ffff00' does not work (causes no error but does not set the background either).  I have to use a var for the assignment because the information is coming from somewhere else, but I can't figure out how to make the backgroundColor respect a String value.  Is there some conversion I have to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure that your function actually returns something. So do `function someFunctionThatReturnsString() { return "#fff000"; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some conversion I have to do?

No, there isn't. It doesn't matter if you use a string literal or a variable.

You have misdiagnosed the problem.

See [a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZQ8n/1/).

Comment: I _hate_ anonymous downvoting. It should be made mandatory to leave a comment if you downvote.

Comment: Thanks!  I had a `String.valueOf` conversion of that value because I was troubleshooting an earlier problem and that seems to be what caused the issue.  Once I removed it, it worked as you demonstrated.